# Java Inheritance constructor issue

Tags: java, oop, constructor

I basically try to send the parent's parameters through the child constructor.

Parent:

```
    public class Animal
{
    protected String name;
    protected int age;
    protected int weight;
    protected int height;

    public Animal(String Name,int Age,int Weight,int Height)
    {
        name = Name;
        age = Age;
        weight = Weight;
        height = Height;
    }
}
```

Child:

```
    public class Mammals extends Animal {

    protected String haircolor;

    public Mammals(String HairColor,int Age,int Weight,int Height)
    {
        super(Age,Weight,Height);
        haircolor = HairColor;
    }

    public String Walk()
    {
        return "Walking...";
    }
}
```

from some reason I keep getting an error.

Comment: What about the name? The super constructor is waiting for a name as first argument.

Comment: **3 parameters != 4 parameters**.

Comment: The wording of the error message itself is often critical. Don't just think of it as "an error", read it carefully and see what it's talking about.

Answer (score 4):

The error comes from

```
super(Age,Weight,Height);
```

because the super-constructor has four parameters and you're passing only three.

Since you don't have a `name` for the `Child`, you can pass `null`.

```
super(null, Age, Weight, Height);
```

Also, consider following [code-conventions](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html).

Comment: I believe the best would be to add the name parameter to the child constructor.

Comment: Well ... possibly the `Child` is a nameless ghoul. :)

Comment: You're right, I forgot this eventuality. My fault. :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a parent constructor with 3 arguments: super(Age,Weight,Height);

Answer (score 2):

```
super(Age,Weight,Height);
```

This should have four arguments passed, but you are passing three.
Check!

Answer (score 0):

Your base class `Animal` has a parameterized constructor having 4 parameters -

> public Animal(String Name,int Age,int Weight,int Height)

But you are passing only 3 arguments while calling it from child class -

> super(Age,Weight,Height);

Here, you are missing `name` argument of base class constructor. As kocko said, If you do not want to pass anything to name parameter then you can pass `null` to the parent class constructor.

> super(null,Age,Weight,Height)

The thing is that, you must pass all the arguments to the constructor or overload the constructor accordingly.

The error might have stated the reason behind it. Please read the errors carefully. They themselves resolve the syntax errors most of the times.

And also, Java follows `camelCase` naming convention. So your parameters' names should be name, age, weight, height, hairColor, etc. Its not related to your question, but it will definitely help you in future.